# How do I make the "Inserted" return one value per insertion into the table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

```
USE CIS111_BookStoreMC
GO

IF OBJECT_ID('AssetsMC_INSERT_UPDATE') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TRIGGER AssetsMC_INSERT_UPDATE
GO

CREATE TRIGGER AssetsMC_INSERT_UPDATE
    ON Assets
    AFTER INSERT,UPDATE
AS
BEGIN

    IF (((SELECT Description FROM Assets WHERE Description IN (SELECT Description FROM Inserted)) = 'Desk') AND
        ((SELECT Cost FROM Assets WHERE Cost IN (SELECT Cost FROM Inserted)) > 200.00))
 
        
    BEGIN
            RAISERROR('Desk cost should be less than $200.00', 11, 1)
            ROLLBACK TRAN   
            RETURN;     
    END
END
```

I do realize that "Inserted" is returning more than one value because I am inserting multiple values into the assets table as such

```
USE CIS111_BookStoreMC
INSERT INTO Assets
    (Description, Cost, PurchaseDate, Category, LocationID)
VALUES
    ('Laptop', 925.99, '2019-01-11', 'Computers', 1),
    ('Laptop', 925.99, '2019-01-11', 'Computers', 2),
    ('Laptop', 925.99, '2019-01-11', 'Computers', 1),
    ('Laptop', 925.99, '2019-01-11', 'Computers', 2),
    ('Server', 6000.00, '2019-01-11', 'Computers', 1),
    ('Server', 6000.00, '2019-01-11', 'Computers', 2),
    ('Desk', 199.99, '2019-01-16', 'Furniture', 1),
    ('Desk', 350.00, '2019-01-16', 'Furniture', 1),
    ('Desk', 199.00, '2019-01-16', 'Furniture', 2),
    ('Desk', 170.00, '2019-01-16', 'Furniture', 2),
    ('File Cabinet', 1200.00, '2019-01-16', 'Furniture', 1),
    ('File Cabinet', 1200.00, '2019-01-16', 'Furniture', 2),
    ('Water Cooler', 550.00, '2019-01-16', 'Miscellaneous', 2),
    ('Water Cooler', 560.00, '2019-01-16', 'Miscellaneous', 1)
```

How would I go about implementing this trigger to run for each insertion into the table?

Comment: The `inserted` and `deleted` virtual tables always contain the set of rows affected. Do you want your check to cause the entire insert to fail if any row fails validation or only prevent the one bad row(s) and raise an error while still inserting the remaining rows of the batch?

Comment: hey @stu I would like it to raise an error while still inserting the remaining rows in the batch.

Comment: please note that I have been told this here in this question down there in the answers "You can only apply this to the whole INSERT, so if your INSERT inserts 25 rows and only one of them is a desk for over $200 - you can only abort the WHOLE INSERT - you cannot just ignore / abort single rows in a trigger. Either the trigger is okay with the whole operation - or it aborts the whole operation - there's no "pick and choose"....." @stu

Comment: That's true for `after` triggers yes, but the alternative is to use a custom insert or update using `instead of` triggers.

Comment: Why are you *really* trying to achieve here? If you want to process that data in your `inserted` object one row at a time you have a design flaw.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach you could consider would be to use an `instead of` trigger. This gives you the ability to validate the insert or update completely since it does not happen at all, instead your trigger runs and you can choose how to proceed.

For this kind of use-case I prefer to keep the insert and update operations separate with a trigger for each.

The bare-bones idea is to actually insert or update in the trigger only the qualifying rows, and then act on the failing rows eg raise an error - or more normally - just log those row(s) to a separate table for reporting etc.

You would likely want to implement a `rules` table and join to this to determine which rows will fail or pass.

Your triggers would look something like the following

```
create trigger AssetsMC_INSERT
on Assets
instead of insert
as

insert into Assets (Description, Cost, PurchaseDate, Category, LocationID)
select Description, Cost, PurchaseDate, Category, LocationID
from inserted
where not exists (select * from Inserted where Description = 'Desk' and Cost > 200.00)

if exists (select * from Inserted where Description = 'Desk' and Cost > 200.00)
begin
    raiserror('Desk cost should be less than $200.00', 0, 1)     
end

go

create trigger AssetsMC_UNPDATE
on Assets
instead of update
as

update a set
    Description = i.Description,
    Cost = i.Cost,
    PurchaseDate = i.PurchaseDate,
    Category = i.Category,
    LocationID = i.LocationId
from inserted i join Assets a on a.Id=i.Id
where not exists (select * from Inserted where Description = 'Desk' and Cost > 200.00)

if exists (select * from Inserted where Description = 'Desk' and Cost > 200.00)
begin
    raiserror('Desk cost should be less than $200.00', 0, 1)     
end

go
```

Comment: While you CAN use an instead of trigger to do this, it is a very bad idea. The back end should not lie to an application. If application inserts x rows, it will expect to find x rows after insertion. In addition, every statement is atomic. A failure (indicated by an error) should cause the statement to be aborted and it should cause the application to rollback the transaction.

Answer (score 1):

You wouldn't use a trigger for this.  You would use a check constraint:

```
alter table assets add constraint chk_desk_price
    check (not (description = 'Desk' and price > 200.0) );
```